# How to upload multiple files from directory to S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, digital-ocean, s3cmd

I have a directory on an Ubuntu, with 340K images, 45GB of total size! Is there an efficient way to transfer them all to an S3 of **DigitalOcean**?

I thought of using `s3cmd put` or `s3cmd sync` but I'm guessing that would perform the `put` operation on every single file individually.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the https://github.com/mishudark/s3-parallel-put, which achieves higher throughput by multithreading but still individual files will be uploaded using single PUT operations since its happening in parallel entire operation will be done sooner. The throughput depends on factors like no of CPU, network bandwidth etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried to transfer 2700 files (400MB) as a test, with 100 processes and finished in 30s! Sometimes though, it slowed-down and logged  `(BotoServerError: 503 Slow Down)`. Do you know how to figure out the best number of processes?

Comment: Generally if your process is more CPU bound, then have ideal thing would be N process/Threads in N core machine, and in our case it since it is more IO bound(n/w is IO) you can have 2 or 3 threads per core, But Don't have ratio like 10 or more Threads to 1 Core, lot of time will be wasted in context switching. Ideal thing for IO bound is start with 2*N(N -no of core) threads and slowly increase the number and until you hit a optimal number after which your performance starts degrading, assume you have 2 or 4 core machine and ran 100 process then it is might not be optimal, reduce the count.